# SalesForce as IdP in Azure ACS

Tags: azure, salesforce

Is there any way to use SalesForce as IdP in Azure ACS.

(in Azure ACS i can see the list google,Yahoo, as IdP)

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding SalesForce as an ADFS Provider?
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services

In the Azure ACS, add a new Identity provider, and choose `WS-Federation identity provider (e.g. Microsoft AD FS 2.0)`